# Optimal method to select `n` farthest points from a set of 2-D points

Tags: php, algorithm

I have set of (latitude,longitude) coordinates.

```
(13.0180552378288,77.6811561227539)
(12.9905166666667,77.7278116666667)
(12.9381400000000,77.7486000000000)
and so on..............there can be upto 100 point
```

I am actually Implementing `k-means` algorithm where I need `k initial centroids`.

I want to select those `k` points such that they are farthest from each other.

PS. I have a function that takes two locations and give distance between them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any order, in which these points are saved?

Comment: @ Purushottam zende  Basically, I have an array of latitude and logitude eg:  `$locations=[["lat"=>x1,"lng"=>y1],["lat"=>x2,"lng"=>y2]];`

Comment: So these are randomly saved points with no connection to each other, right? like not left to right or increasing or decreasing ?

Comment: yes @Purushottamzende These are randomly stored location coordinates

Comment: "I am actually Implementing k-means algorithm where I need k initial centroids" does it mean that your points are not spread all around the sphere, right?

Comment: There something fishy in the "they are farthest from each other." - What do you want to maximize: the sum of distances between them, the area delimited on the surface, what? Because if you pick the points on the max distance, there may be cases in which the rest of the choices will bring in much shorter distances into the solution.

Comment: I want to maximize the sum of distances between them.

Comment: @Jagrati you could use [Farthest-first-traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farthest-first_traversal) to find that set of points

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you randomly cordinates are in array

```
    $random_cordinates = array();
```

Make another array for distance saving, like

```
    $distnce_array = array();
```

Now , in foreach loop , compare the first elemnt with all other elements for distance. And save the codinates into third array $distnce_array with its index and matched index
like, for first time value at index 1 is compared with all the other index and it matched the 7th element, so it will be like

```
    $distnce_array[0] => 7;
```

and so for others also, but dont compare the previous cordinates when moving to next index, like when ur at index 5 dont check for 0,1,2,3,4 etc. And only store the values if its bigger than the stored value. 
Witht his ur no of comparing cordiates will be less after evey loop.

Comment: But this will only work when I want to select two farthest points. What if I want to select 3 or 4 farthest points from set of points.?

Comment: Well then save each points distance with each other. It will be like permutaion and Combination. You will need each distance to comapre each other. Rest all will be same, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that, if your goal is to

> find a set of n points, N, from among a set M (|M| >= |N|) where the
>   sum of distances between points in N is maximal

you can solve this using the following algorithm:

```
Take the bounding-polygon of the global set of points, M
Call the set of points that delimit this polygon P; if
   1. |P| = |N|, then you have finished. 
      All points in P should belong to N
   2. |P| > |N|, then you need to discard points from P. 
      For each point in P, 
          calculate its score as the delta-sum that it adds to the total. 
      Remove the lowest-scoring point until you reach |N|
   3. |P| < |N|, then you need to add points to P. 
      For each point in M, 
          calculate its score as the delta-sum that it would add to the total. 
      Add the highest-scoring point until you reach |N|
```

The intuitive "proof" of correctness is that any point inside the polygon delimited by P has a shorter delta-distance to members of P than the point in P that it would replace. *However, this is not a formal proof.*

Implementing the algorithm in PHP should be straightforward. You can use an O(n) algorithm to [find P](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) - also available [in PHP](https://github.com/benpoulson/PHP-ConvexHull). And then you would need `O((|N| - |P|) * |M|))` in the worse case to add points (case 3); or `O((|P| - |N|)^2)` if you need to discard points (case 2).